# blit in FigureCanvasTkAgg with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to use the TkAgg backend for matplotlib for a bit of real-time plotting. [Here](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations), one can read that the `FigureCanvasTkAgg` class automatically implements `canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)` and `canvas.restore_region(background)`, that are the prerequisites for the use of `blit()`, for which the method documentation can be found [here](http://doc.astro-wise.org/matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg.html).

Thus, I tried the code below (source of inspiration [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html)):

```
#calibration graph
calib_frame = tk.LabelFrame(r_cont, text='probe angle calibration', padx=5, pady=5)
calib_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='ns')
fig = Figure(figsize=(2,2))
calib_plot = fig.add_subplot(111)
axis = np.arange(0,100)
s = np.sin(2*math.pi*axis) #static data for debugging
calib_plot.plot(axis, s)
calib_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=calib_frame)
calib_canvas.blit()
calib_canvas.show()
calib_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=0)
```

Which does not work, because the `calib_canvas.blit()` method is not correctly implemented (I think...). I understand what `blit()` does, and I would like to `blit()`the axes bounding box, but I do not understand how to implement it and the references I read did not help. Can someone help me with a correct implementation, please?

the error I get from the code above:

```
>>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\try.py", line 450, in <module>
 calib_canvas.blit(bbox=None)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 353, in blit
 tkagg.blit(self._tkphoto, self.renderer._renderer, bbox=bbox, colormode=2)
AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasTkAgg' object has no attribute 'renderer'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the error, which is due to calling `blit()` before the initial `show()`event. Just invert the two lines, and the error disappears.